# Show current search paths for a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to troubleshoot a view and why it can't find the editor templates. Obviously it has to do with how we've configured the search paths in the `CustomRazorViewEngine`, but just looking at it, it should be working. Instead, it's rendering the default MVC editor templates, because it can't find the custom ones.

How can I display the list of search paths for a view, or trigger an error so that it shows me the search paths it's looking for?

Comment: have you tried using glimpse (http://getglimpse.com)?  There is a NuGet package that contains this MVC debugger.  It may be useful to track down your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, our environment is a bit constrained and won't be able to easily do this. Would prefer an option that doesn't require a separate package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best way, but adding this to the controller worked for me:

```
var searchedLocations = ViewEngines.Engines.[0]
    .FindPartialView(this.ControllerContext, "MyModel", false)
    .SearchedLocations
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Cool. If you were concerned about bloating your code, you could add a breakpoint in the controller block and then use the value you had for the assignment in the above expression for as a variable to watch, i.e. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290869(v=vs.71).aspx