# Display alternative search paths for the current view in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

For debugging purposes I would like to know the other view paths that could have been used instead of the Razor view that ended up being rendered. Normally it wouldn't be hard to guess but I'm using custom `IViewLocationExpander`s that can dynamically vary search paths. Is it possible to get that information in ASP.NET Core MVC for any view render attempt?

Similar to this question, [Show current search paths for a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867259/show-current-search-paths-for-a-view), but for ASP.NET Core.

My specific case is a call to `Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserRole)` which ends up rendering my EditorTemplates/Object.cshtml file instead of a EditorTemplates/UserRole.cshtml that I have in a non-standard location a custom `IViewLocationExpander` should surface. Apparently I've put my UserRole.cshtml in a location that I think should be searched but is not.

Comment: Hmm looks like the view engine in ASP.Net Core only gives you the list of searched locations if it fails to find the view, but I guess that's not really what you want?

Comment: Correct @DavidG the search paths of that exception is essentially what I want except I want it when a view is found and rendered. I added more details to my question.

Answer (score 0):

The following approximates what a call to `Html.EditorFor` does behind the scenes and works for my current situation, but I'm hopeful someone else can provide a general solution to this problem.

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ICompositeViewEngine ViewEngine
<pre>@string.Join("\n", ViewEngine
    .FindView(ViewContext, "EditorTemplates/" + 
        (ViewData.ModelMetadata.TemplateHint ?? ViewData.ModelMetadata.DataTypeName ?? ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType.Name), isMainPage: false)
    .SearchedLocations)</pre>
```

Comment: Thank @DavidG I forgot the `@inject` statement. I updated the code.

Comment: Does this work when it finds the view successfully though? My comment above is because I don't think it does.

Comment: @DavidG I'm using it now in my EditorTemplates/Object.cshtml view, and it helped me figure out what I did wrong. Why do you think it wouldn't work?